# Custom control to get coordinates from a point in Google API

Tags: javascript, .net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using JavaScript Google API to build a map for my site (that is going to work for tablets, not for PCs)

I am getting all the markers from the .NET doc;

I want to make a new custom control, and when a user will choose it he will able to click on some point on the map and get the coordinates to a text field.

So I know how to make a new control, and I know how to click on some point in the map and get the coordinates:

When I click I get the `lat` and `long`:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "rightclick", function(event) {
    var latFromMap = event.latLng.lat();
    var lngFromMap = event.latLng.lng();
    // populate yor box/field with lat, lng
    document.getElementById("lat").value = latFromMap;
    document.getElementById("long").value = lngFromMap;
});
```

And to make a control (that will take us back to center):

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(outer, 'click', function() {
  map.setCenter(getcenter)
});
```

Now. I want to connect them. So only when I click on the control I will be able to check the lat/long in some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a new styledMapType as described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#creating_a_styledmaptype) (you don't need the styling, simply create the mapType and add it to the controls).

When you do so you have 2 results at once, that you need for your project: 
The control, and a property that you can check  everytime to determine if the control is active, the **`mapTypeId`**

Applying the click would be easy then:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
  if(this.mapTypeId=='mapTypeIdOfTheStyledMap'){
    //execute click-action
  }
});
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/kbXGd/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/kbXGd/)

Comment: thanks its good, and i found another way to do it: just to add the control a listener that work only one time like this:               function addClickListener(){
                    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce.........}